# AngularJs Tests: assert the path is changed

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, chai

I want to assert that the URL will in fact be updated on a certain condition.

When I log the $location, this is printed:

```
 Location{replace: function () { ... }, assign: function () { ... }, ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList{0: 'http://localhost:9876', length: 1}, origin: 'http://localhost:9876', hash: '', search: '', pathname: '/context.html', port: '9876', hostname: 'localhost', host: 'localhost:9876', protocol: 'http:', href: 'http://localhost:9876/context.html', reload: function reload() { ... }}
```

Comment: What is your question? If you have access to $location then you should have all of the information you need for your test. Is there something you are unsure or confused about?

Comment: There is no path... I want to see the window location but instead I see the href = http://localhost:9876/context.html. Clear?